# Como exibir mensagem no AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou trabalhando com angular e preciso adicionar uma mensagem na tela ao ser precionado o botão verificar codigo. Um mensagem de erro ou sucesso.

**Controller do angular**

```
angular.module().controller(){ 
        vm.validarProtocolo = function(){          
            //exibir mensagem na tela
        };
}
```

**Código Html**

```
<input type="text" name="protocolo" ng-model="brSafe.protocolo">
<button ng-click="validarProtocolo()">Validar Protocolo</button>
```

Comment: Você precisa exibir a mensagem, mas, faltou como você deseja, tem alguma idéia um simples `alert` do javascript resolve?

Comment: Ja usei o alert. Não funcionou..Preciso que mensagem seja uma mensagem de texto ao lado do botao um spam vermelhor

Comment: se precisa em qual momento, ao clicar o botão?

Comment: isso mesmo. Quando clicar no botão é chamada essa função: validarProcotolo

Comment: Detalhe um pouco mais sua necessidade, Alex. "Preciso adicionar uma mensagem" - Adicionar aonde? Que tipo? Qual critério? Da maneira como sua pergunta foi formulada, a resposta do Thiago está plenamente correta.

Comment: Thiago respondeu a minha pergunta. Algo simples e direto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De uma forma simples, fazendo uma função exibir uma mensagem:

```js
var app = angular.module('root', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "";
    
    $scope.validarProtocolo = function(){     
        $scope.message = "TESTE";
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="root" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-if="message">{{message}}</p>
  <button ng-click="validarProtocolo()">TESTE</button>
</div>
```